# PrintWindow distorts window

Tags: wpf, windows, winapi, gdi

I try to capture screenshots of a window and save it to a video. I use `PrintWindow()` to capture the screenshots. When my app is running and some other window is moved over the window being captured, I see the captured window getting distorted(traces of the moved over window remains on the captured window); however the saved video doesn't have any distortions.

I suspected a redraw of the window might be needed and tried `InvalidateRect()`, `UpdateWindow()` after `PrintWindow()`, but it wasn't of any help.

The issue is not observed on all the systems. I had the issue on Vista system and not on Win7. I suspect it happens on systems where the window is continuously drawn when dragged and not on systems where just a black border when the window is dragged.

Comment: Have you tried changing the dragging setting and confirming whether this is the problem?

Comment: just tried it and it was not the case, my assumption was wrong(ie. it doesn't happen on all the systems where window moves continuously on drag)